# Clear static data on ngOnDestroy, after getting the data from service

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-lifecycle-hooks

I want to clear the data on ngOnDestroy. I am getting this static data from a service.
Current scenario is I am using the same component for add-edit and I just want to clear the temporary static data once the user is done with editing.

```
export class LeadsDefaultDataService {

tempData;

private leadsDefaults = {
leads: {
  data: [
    {
      type: 'page_title',
      data: {
        title: 'Enter data',
      }
    },
    {
      type: 'page_layout',
      data: {
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
      }
    }
}
};


/**
 * Constructor
 */
 constructor(
 ) {}

 /**
  *  Function used to return the default data of qrCategory
  * @param category: Name of the category
  */
  getLeadsDefaultData(category: string) {
   return this.leadsDefaults[category].data;
  }
}
```

In the component:

```
constructor(
  private defaultData: LeadsDefaultDataService,
 ) {
}



   // For getting the data
   this.leadsData =  this.defaultData.getLeadsDefaultData('leads');


  // Reset the leadsData.
  ngOnDestroy() {
   this.leadsData = null; // not working....
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just nulling reference. As a better way, you can do it by exposing method in service like below

```
export class LeadsDefaultDataService {
 .......
  setLeadData(category: string, value: any){
    this.leadsDefaults[category].data = value;
  }
}
```

and call this method from component

```
 ngOnDestroy() {
    this.defaultData.setLeadData('leads', null);
  }
```